# .Net Fakes - Expression Term

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, microsoft-fakes

I've created a Fake Dll (System.Web.Mvc) with VS2013 for my Test Solution and I am using the following Syntax to Resolve the Data for:

```
bool solved = helper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(key, out state);
```

I am using this Shim (that works fine):

```
ShimModelStateDictionary.AllInstances.TryGetValueStringModelStateOut =
    delegate(ModelStateDictionary dictionary, string s, out ModelState @out)
    {
            @out = new ModelState();
           return true;
    };
```

But there must be an alternate Solution with the following Syntax:

```
ShimModelStateDictionary.AllInstances.TryGetValueStringModelStateOut = (ModelStateDictionary dictionary, string s, out ModelState @out) => ...
```

But I don't know how to solve this with an Lambda Expression? I am not shure how this works, perhaps someone can give me a hint or can tell me how this syntax works.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to match the method signature. The method takes a string and an output variable, so those need names. Then you need a method body (Requiring curly braces because you need two lines) which assigns the out variable and returns the correct return type. I haven't tested this code myself, but I'm fairly certain it will work. Normally, I use resharper to suggest the lambdas, and am quite familiar with the syntax now.

```
ShimModelStateDictionary
  .AllInstances
  .TryGetValueStringModelStateOut = 
    (s, out m) =>
      {
        m = new ModelState();
        return true;
      }
```

^Should be exactly what you need.